# How to pop current Monday by clicking button in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wanna build a button in Google spreadsheets with App Script. The request goes like below:

1. Click the button named "Refresh"
2. Pop the date of the Monday of the current week, for example, today is 5/7/2021, then the cell value should be filled with 5/3/2021.

I know it can be achieved by writing the Script, but I have no idea how to achieve it.

Thanks,
Jet

==========================================================================

```
function popMonday() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[4].getRange('L1');
SpreadsheetApp.setCurrentCell(cell);

var selection = SpreadsheetApp.getSelection();
var currentCell = selection.getCurrentCell();

const today = new Date();
const tw = today.getDay();
const dateObj = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate() - (tw - (tw > 0 ? 1 : -6))));
const str = Utilities.formatDate(dateObj, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy");

currentCell.setValue(str);}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the date of this Monday from today using Google Apps Script.
- You want to open a dialog including the retrieved date.

In this case, how about the following script?

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  const today = new Date();
  const tw = today.getDay();
  const dateObj = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate() - (tw - (tw > 0 ? 1 : -6))));
  const str = Utilities.formatDate(dateObj, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy");
  Browser.msgBox(str); // or SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(str);
}
```

- In this case, I thought that retrieving the day of the week using `getDay()` is important.
- When you run the function `myFunction`, a dialog is opened. You can see the date in the dialog.
- From `then the cell value should be filled with 5/3/2021.`, when you use the following script instead of `Browser.msgBox(str);`, when the script is run, a dialog is opened and also the value of `dateObj` is put to the active cell.

  ```
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(str), "sample");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().setValue(dateObj);
  ```

#### References:

- [getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)
- [formatDate(date, timeZone, format)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format)

Comment: Hi Tanaike, copy that, the major part of the script is working, here is the completed one works for my scenario: